# Get prefixes of css filters with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, css, filter, modernizr

I'm trying to use the Modernizr.prefixed() function to avoid writing all the vendors code in my JS but it doesn't seems to work.
I would like to use it for css filters, here is my code:
`Modernizr.prefixed('filter') // returns 'filter' on Chrome which actually needs '-webkit-filter'`

I already looked at the source code of Modernizr but it didn't helped (https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/filters.js).

Notice that the feature detection for filters is present in my Modernizr build.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [this is really a chromium bug](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/981).

The fine young gentlemen stucox provides a work around for this specific case, though

```
// This could be written more efficiently, but shows the technique at least
function getFilterPrefixed () {
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    var testValue = 'grayscale(1)';
    var prop;
    var i;

// `Modernizr._prefixes` is a list of known (common) vendor prefixes
for (i = 0; i < Modernizr._prefixes.length; i++) {
    prop = Modernizr._prefixes[i] + 'filter';

    // Set-and-check: if the property holds a valid value, it's the one
    elem.style[prop] = testValue;
    if (elem.style[prop] == testValue) {
        return prop;
    }
  }
}
```